# package signalflowdiagram

Tags: packages, installing

I am using Miktex2.9. I added `\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}` to draw block 
diagrams. Then an error message appeared

```
"file signalflowdiagram.sty not found"
```

Where do I place the `.sty` file? Please show me how to do step by step!

Answer (score 2):

I supposed that you download the `.sty` somewhere on internet ([read here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/), [download package here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/)). In This case put it in the same folder than your `.tex` file.

Otherwise you have to update the package list of MikTeX and should run it as admin. There is lot of post on TeX.SE about this point.